# FlutterFirebase Is it possible to add text data about photo and photo?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I got confused in this situation. Im working on a new project like adding photo and description or other text input. I read a article it is doing this but it's old article.
My app like this; user will add a photo, title and description. Just like a simple Instagram.
(Honestly Im not gonna do instagram. :] )

(Also you can find it here:
https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-slider-like-reflectly/.)

Is it possible to do that in Firebase Firestore ? Or should i use Cloud Storage?

If I have to use Cloud Storage, how can I add photo description or other text input.

I couldn't find any example like this in Google.

Answer (score 3):

For a user to upload images to your app you would need something like Firebase Storage to host the images, so you will need Cloud Storage anyways. regarding the description, its possible to attach custom metadata to files in Cloud Storage (description, location, title etc...) However if you are going for something more complex, using Firestore together with Storage is probably your best bet. You could store a document for each image in an image collection in firestore and have the `imageUrl` field point to the Hosting URL along with any other data you might want

Comment: Hmmm. Im so close to get it. Can you suggest me any article or video about Cloud Storage adding image's description and title ?

Comment: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage/#adding-metadata

Answer (score 2):

You need to use both, you should upload the image in cloud storage and after upload you will get a link of this file. Then you can add this link in firestore document with other information as well such as description or other text input like you wanted.